# How RX button tap handling actually had been implemented?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Does anyone know how RX button tap handling actually had been implemented?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/tree/master/RxSwift) is all the code. Find it.

Answer (score 1):

If we looked in depth into RxCocoa code. To be more specific into the "Reactive" struct, we could find it has an extension where it's base is UIButton and in this extension, there is a tap variable of type ControlEvent which return a controlEvent(.touchUpInside).

**So the question is how controlEvent(.touchUpInside) handles the control events?!**

- controlEvent(_ controlEvents: UIControlEvents) -> ControlEvent<()> .. is a function inside extenion for "Reactive" struct where it's base is UIControl.
  And when our base is UIButton, which also extend UIControl, So we can call this function too when our base is UIButton and this is our case and this the function which handles UIButton taps (which only specified in RxCocoa as in extension).

**How controlEvent function work and handle touchupInside?!**

- controllEvent just adding target selector to UIControll throw custom ControlTarget class in RxCocoa which pass escaping Callback to UIControll to emit onNext in a specific control event (touchupInside in our case).

read this classes in RxCoca if my explanation is not good enough :)

1. UIButton+Rx.swift
2. ControlEvent.swift
3. UIControl+Rx.swift
4. ControlTarget.swift

Comment: How they could keep a reference to the target, with out using objc_association?

Comment: The disposable that gets returned is the target.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Reactive where Base: UIButton {
    /// Reactive wrapper for `TouchUpInside` control event.
    public var tap: ControlEvent<Void> {
        return controlEvent(.touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

Comment: While this answer might resolve the OP's question, it is suggested that you explain how it works and why it resolves the issue. This helps new developers understand what is going on and how to fix this and similar issues themselves. Thanks for contributing!